# npm start command gives error : http-server:command not found , code: ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, npm, centos, npm-start

I am new be to node js . started to set up node js project .

Got error when npm start command is used.

npm start

```
> sigma@1.1.0 start /usr/local/UserProfile/TitanUI
> http-server -p 8080    
sh: http-server: command not found    
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! sigma@1.1.0 start: `http-server -p 8080`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! Failed at the sigma@1.1.0 start script 'http-server -p 8080'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sigma package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -p 8080
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs sigma
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sigma
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/UserProfile/TitanUI/npm-debug.log
```

These are the versions of centos , npm and node js.

centos:6.6

npm:3.10

nodejs:6.7.0
I guess I have latest versions only..Please help me if any one knows about this.

Comment: Can you please post your package.json file?

Comment: Hi issue is solved Thanks .. Removing the node modules and , npm install  solved the issue...

Comment: but shouldnt the node_modules folder have an executable?

Answer (score 0):

Removed the node modules folder and ran "npm install" and "npm start" again. This solved the above error.  Thanks!